# Does Optimization Have its Roots in Ancient Geometry?

Tags: geometry, optimization

Recently, I was reading about math problems that existed in Ancient Civilizations. For instance:

- **Dido's Problem**: In ancient mythology, Dido was tasked with laying out the hide of an animal such that area covered by the animal's hide was **maximized**. Dido's Problem was apparently an early statement of the Isoperimetric Inequality  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality) - the **maximum** surface area that can be covered by some length will for a circular shape.
- **Euclidean Distance**: Euclid famously determined the **shortest** distance between two points and the **shortest** distance between a point and a line.

It is not difficult to see that the nature of these problems reflect modern optimization ideas - such as finding out the smallest or biggest values a certain quantity can take, given some conditions.

Thus, on an informal level - could we conclude that modern optimization has its roots in ancient geometry? Were ancient civilizations attempting to solve optimization problems far before the modern field of optimization existed?

Thanks!

**Note:** If anyone knows about other similar types of problems (i.e. geometrical optimization) that have existed since ancient times, I would be very interested in knowing about them - please feel free to share them in the comments!

Comment: I guess that's a perspective to have. Depends on what you define as optimization.

Comment: If you wanted to show the quadratic mean of two distinct positive numbers is greater than the arithmetic mean which is greater than the geometric mean, which in turn is greater than the harmonic mean (the last three of which are called Pythagorean means), then this is "obvious" from a [geometric diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MathematicalMeans.svg)

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies!